# How to move files in to new directory based on column values (ID, number)

Tags: pandas, for-loop, terminal, directory, shutil

I have a csv file with filenames in the file_name column and site numbers in the site_number column. I have a directory with files that match the filenames in the file_name column plus and extensions eg .xyz. I have three separate directories I want to move the file names to based on the ID name and site number.

| file_name | site_number |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 1 |
| grape | 1 |
| pear | 2 |
| orange | 3 |

I have all files in the a directory "fruit"  apple.xyz, grape.xyz, pear.xyz, orange.xyz

I have three directories i want to move the files to based on the site number, fruit_1, fruit_2, and fruit_3, i want to move apple.xyz and grape.xyz to fruit_1, pear to fruit_2, and orange to fruit_3.

How can I do this?

Comment: just to clarify- are the filenames things like apple.xyz, or apple_1.xyz, or both?

Comment: the filenames have no number so its apple.xzy

Answer (score 0):

Requires Python >=3.4

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'file_name': ['apple', 'banana', 'grape'],
    'site_number': [1, 1, 2]})

out = "/Users/my_cool_username/Downloads/so/out"
nm = "fruit"

# create the folders we need
df.apply(lambda x: Path.mkdir(Path(out, nm + "_" + str(x['site_number'])), parents=True, exist_ok=True), axis=1)

# move the folders
df.apply(lambda x: Path(x['file_name'] + '.csv').rename(Path(out, nm + "_" + str(x['site_number']), x['file_name'] + '.csv')), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import os, shutil, glob

d = df.set_index('file_name')['site_number']

for file in glob.glob('fruit/*.xyz'):
    base_filename = os.path.basename(file)
    output = f'fruit_{d.get(os.path.splitext(base_filename)[0])}'
    #print (file)
    #print (output)
    shutil.move(file, output)
```